# Workflowy - Stylebot - Is there a way to style css tag where a particular tag/item starts with xxx (e.g. "[ ]" or "evernote://" characters?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, stylebot

Trying to style my Workflowy in Stylebot atm.

I use something like [  ] to denote a tasks (not everything stored in my Workflowy are "tasks") and am wondering if there's a way to code the CSS such that it applies to bullet items that begin with "[  ]" only?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking questions in the [Help]. You should add some *relevant* code to your question. You can use the [Edit] link below your question to do so. You should also make sure to include all the relevant tags when you ask a question so that people with experience in the technologies you're using see it.

Comment: Added tags relevant to the technologies being used

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<html>
<head>   
<style>
.a-checkpoint-list ul{

  list-style-type: none;
 }

  li:before {
  content: "[]";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="a-checkpoint-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```